# Expect Arrays to be equal ignoring order

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

With Jasmine is there a way to test if 2 arrays contain the same elements, but are not necessarily in the same order? ie

```
array1 = [1,2,3];
array2 = [3,2,1];

expect(array1).toEqualIgnoreOrder(array2);//should be true
```

Comment: `expect(array1.sort()).toEqual(array2.sort());` ?

Comment: @raina77ow I guess that would work as well.

Comment: Should I make this an answer?

Comment: @raina77ow It gets a little bit more complicated when its an array of objects. It would be nice if Jasmine had something out of the box for this.

Comment: I didn't find anything great in jasmine itself so actually introduced lodash (or you could use underscore/other js collection library) into my test project for things just like this.

Comment: I like @raina77ow's answer the best. The only caveat is that the `sort` will mutate the input arrays, though that's probably not a big deal. If it causes a problem, you can do `[...array1].sort()`

Answer (score 112):

**Edit**

Jasmine 2.8 adds `arrayWithExactContents` that will succeed if the actual value is an Array that contains all of the elements in the sample in any order.

See [keksmasta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56971251/3892935)

---

**Original (outdated) answer**

If it's just integers or other primitive values, you can [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them before comparing.

```
expect(array1.sort()).toEqual(array2.sort());
```

If its objects, combine it with the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to extract an identifier that will be compared

```
array1 = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
array2 = [{id:3}, {id:2}, {id:1}];

expect(array1.map(a => a.id).sort()).toEqual(array2.map(a => a.id).sort());
```

Comment: the default array sort method uses string comparison for numbers. `"10" < "2" === true`

Comment: `[10, 2, 1].sort() ---> [1, 10, 2]`

Comment: @Shmiddty I dont see how it matters in this case. As long as the order is the same for both arrays, it should be fine.

Comment: Fair point. It is worth noting that `sort` happens in-place, though. (it mutates the instance on which it is called)

Comment: @Shmiddty that's true, but `.map` returns a new array, so you're still not mutating the original.

Comment: The object portion of this answer will not actually verify that the objects match, since it is only comparing the mapped arrays.  You don't need map, `sort` takes an optional function that it can use to do the comparison.

Comment: If for example the sorting key is "id" but there is extra data and those are not equal (but should be) this fails.

Comment: This should not be the first answer as it's outdated. Please see answer below regarding arrayWithExactContents

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv Thank you, I added a note that a different answer is preferred now. Although I'm not sure how it works when comparing objects.

Answer (score 59):

You could use expect.arrayContaining(array) from standard jest:

```
  const expected = ['Alice', 'Bob'];
  it('matches even if received contains additional elements', () => {
    expect(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Eve']).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(expected));
  });
```

Comment: It is not an appropriate answer for this use case as the two arrays in the question are expected to be equal, with only order differing.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Please mark this as the correct answer. @mjarraya just test for the length of both arrays to be the same and you are fine.

Comment: It should not be marked as the correct answer since it is not complete! @enanone

Comment: There are two issues:
1. length needs to be checked. 
expect(actual.length).toEqual(expected.length);

2. It should be jasmine.arrayContaining. https://jasmine.github.io/2.6/introduction#section-Partial_Array_Matching_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.arrayContaining%3C/code%3E

Comment: ```expect([1, 2, 3]).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([3, 3, 3]))``` will still pass, so this should not be used.

Answer (score 51):

jasmine version 2.8 and later has

```
jasmine.arrayWithExactContents()
```

Which expects that an array contains exactly the elements listed, in any order.

```
array1 = [1,2,3];
array2 = [3,2,1];
expect(array1).toEqual(jasmine.arrayWithExactContents(array2))
```

See https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/jasmine.html

Answer (score 23):

The [jest-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended) package provides us few assertions to simplify our tests, it's less verbose and for failing tests the error is more explicit.

For this case we could use [toIncludeSameMembers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended#toincludesamemembersmembers)

```
expect([{foo: "bar"}, {baz: "qux"}]).toIncludeSameMembers([{baz: "qux"}, {foo: "bar"}]);
```

Answer (score 13):

simple...

```
array1 = [1,2,3];
array2 = [3,2,1];

expect(array1).toEqual(jasmine.arrayContaining(array2));
```

Comment: Nice answer! You also need to check that the lengths are equal, otherwise you'll have a false positive on [1,2,3,4] and [3,2,1].

Answer (score 10):

```
// check if every element of array2 is element of array1
// to ensure [1, 1] !== [1, 2]
array2.forEach(x => expect(array1).toContain(x))

// check if every element of array1 is element of array2
// to ensure [1, 2] !== [1, 1]
array1.forEach(x => expect(array2).toContain(x))

// check if they have equal length to ensure [1] !== [1, 1]
expect(array1.length).toBe(array2.length)
```

Comment: Use `.forEach` instead of `.map` to save some time and a bunch of memory.

Comment: Unfortunately this will pass with the following arrays even though they are different: `array1 = [1, 2]`, `array2 = [1, 1]`

Comment: Nice catch @redbmk I added a check for this, thanks!

Comment: I think there's still an issue - what if the arrays are `[1,1,2]` and `[1,2,2]`? Maybe using a Map for each one or something? e.g. `array1.reduce((map, item) => { map.set(item, (map.get(item) || 0) + 1)), new Map())` for both arrays, then loop through them and check that the amounts are the same? Seems like a lot of iterations but would be more thorough.

Comment: Exclusions from the control array may be used (remove element when found, then check length is 0 in the end), but it doesn't worth the effort in regular cases.

Answer (score 4):

Sets ignore order so they can be used here.

```js
expect(new Set(a)).toEqual(new Set(b))
```

Comment: It works nicely for objects (vectorial instances), thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
//Compare arrays without order
//Example
//a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
//a2 = [3, 2, 1, 5, 4]
//isEqual(a1, a2) -> true
//a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
//a2 = [3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6];
//isEqual(a1, a2) -> false


function isInArray(a, e) {
  for ( var i = a.length; i--; ) {
    if ( a[i] === e ) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isEqArrays(a1, a2) {
  if ( a1.length !== a2.length ) {
    return false;
  }
  for ( var i = a1.length; i--; ) {
    if ( !isInArray( a2, a1[i] ) ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses forEach to compare every element in each array on a unique object property (used `status` here).

```
const expected = [ 
     { count: 1, status: "A" },
     { count: 3, status: "B" },
];
result.forEach((item) => {
     expect(expected.find(a => a.status === item.status)).toEqual(item);
})
```

Comment: this answer only deals with all results being found in `expected`.  It only asserts that `result` is a subset of `expected`.  You need to reverse it and assert that all expected's items are in `result`

Answer (score 0):

This approach has worse theoretical worst-case run-time performance, but, because it does not perform any writes on the array, it might be faster in many circumstances (haven't tested performance yet):

WARNING: As Torben pointed out in the comments, this approach only works if both arrays have unique (non-repeating) elements (just like several of the other answers here).

```js
/**
 * Determine whether two arrays contain exactly the same elements, independent of order.
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103252/expect-arrays-to-be-equal-ignoring-order/48973444#48973444
 */
function cmpIgnoreOrder(a, b) {
  const { every, includes } = _;
  return a.length === b.length && every(a, v => includes(b, v));
}

// the following should be all true!
const results = [
  !!cmpIgnoreOrder([1,2,3], [3,1,2]),
  !!cmpIgnoreOrder([4,1,2,3], [3,4,1,2]),
  !!cmpIgnoreOrder([], []),
  !cmpIgnoreOrder([1,2,3], [3,4,1,2]),
  !cmpIgnoreOrder([1], []),
  !cmpIgnoreOrder([1, 3, 4], [3,4,5])
];

console.log('Results: ', results)
console.assert(_.reduce(results, (a, b) => a && b, true), 'Test did not pass!');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it creates lots of copies? `Array#sort` sorts arrays in-place.

Comment: Fails for these arrays: [1,1,2,3], [3,3,1,2].

Comment: @TorbenKohlmeier Thanks, I updated my answer (admitting defeat in regard to 
 non-unique arrays)

Answer (score 0):

```
function equal(arr1, arr2){
    return arr1.length === arr2.length
    &&
    arr1.every((item)=>{
        return arr2.indexOf(item) >-1
    }) 
    &&
    arr2.every((item)=>{
        return arr1.indexOf(item) >-1
    })
}
```

The idea here is to first determine if the length of the two arrays are same, then check if all elements are in the other's array.

Comment: This does not take into account the frequency of items:
`equal([1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2])` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will work for any number or arrays

https://gist.github.com/tvler/cc5b2a3f01543e1658b25ca567c078e4

```
const areUnsortedArraysEqual = (...arrs) =>
  arrs.every((arr, i, [first]) => !i || arr.length === first.length) &&
  arrs
    .map(arr =>
      arr.reduce(
        (map, item) => map.set(item, (map.get(item) || 0) + 1),
        new Map(),
      ),
    )
    .every(
      (map, i, [first]) =>
        !i ||
        [...first, ...map].every(([item]) => first.get(item) === map.get(item)),
    );
```

Some tests (a few answers to this question don't account for arrays with multiple items of the same value, so [1, 2, 2] and [1, 2] would incorrectly return true)

```
[1, 2] true
[1, 2], [1, 2] true
[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2] true
[1, 2], [2, 1] true
[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1] true
[1, 2], [1, 2, 3] false
[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2] false
[1, 2, 2], [1, 2] false
[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2] false
[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3] false
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is great for arrays where each item is unique. If not, you can add in something to check for duplicates...

```js
tests = [
  [ [1,0,1] , [0,1,1] ],
  [ [1,0,1] , [0,0,1] ], //breaks on this one...
  [ [2,3,3] , [2,2,3] ], //breaks on this one also...
  [ [1,2,3] , [2,1,3] ],
  [ [2,3,1] , [1,2,2] ],
  [ [2,2,1] , [1,3,2] ]
]

tests.forEach(function(test) {
  console.log('eqArraySets( '+test[0]+' , '+test[1]+' ) = '+eqArraySets( test[0] , test[1] ));
});


function eqArraySets(a, b) {
 if ( a.length !== b.length ) { return false; }
 for ( var i = a.length; i--; ) {
  if ( !(b.indexOf(a[i])>-1) ) { return false; }
  if ( !(a.indexOf(b[i])>-1) ) { return false; }
 }
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currenly a matcher for this USE CASE:

https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended/pull/122/files

```js
test('passes when arrays match in a different order', () => {
  expect([1, 2, 3]).toMatchArray([3, 1, 2]);
  expect([{ foo: 'bar' }, { baz: 'qux' }]).toMatchArray([{ baz: 'qux' }, { foo: 'bar' }]);
});
```

Comment: But that is part of `jest-extended`, i.e., not available as a core Jest functionality, right?

Comment: there is `toIncludeSameMembers` in `jest-extended`. I don't know whether this is equivalent

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this helper function (for TypeScript). It makes sure that arrays that have non unique elements are supported as well.

```
function expectArraysToBeEqualIgnoringOrder<T>(arr1: T[], arr2: T[]) {

    while(arr1.length > 0) {

        expect(arr1.length).toEqual(arr2.length)

        const elementToDelete = arr1[0]

        arr1 = arr1.filter(element => element !== elementToDelete)
        arr2 = arr2.filter(element => element !== elementToDelete)

    }

    expect(arr2.length).toEqual(0)

}
```

Many of the other asnwers do not correctly handle cases like this:

```
array1: [a, b, b, c]
array2: [a, b, c, c]
```

Here the number of elements in both arrays is the same and both arrays contain all elements from the other array, yet they are different arrays and the test should fail.
It runs in O(n^2) (precisely (n^2 + n) / 2), so it's not suitable for very large arrays, but it's suitable for arrays that are not easilly sorted and therefore can not be compared in O(n * log(n))